# Spark-Submit exception SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure

Tags: apache-spark

Whenever I tried to run a `spark-submit` command like the one below I'm getting an exception. Please could someone suggest what's going wrong here.

My command:

```
spark-submit --class com.xyz.MyTestClass --master spark://<spark-master-IP>:7077  SparkTest.jar

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0.0:0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: TID 7 on host <hostname> failed for unknown reason
Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1033)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1017)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1015)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1015)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:633)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:633)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:633)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1207)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Comment: please explain what you want to happen Vs. what is happening now. Thanks

Comment: thanks for the quick reply!! Basically i am reading some data from HDFS using spark, doing some operations on that data and again saving the data in to file in HDFS using spark. So for running this logic in java, i am executing my jar by using Spark-submit, but i am getting the above exception

Comment: Check the worker logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if the parameter

```
--master spark://<spark-master-IP>:7077
```

is what you *actually* have written instead of the actual *IP* of the master node. If so, you should change it and type the *IP* or public *DNS* of the master, such as:

> --master spark://ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:7077

If that's not the case, I would appreciate if you could provide more information about the error of the application, just as pointed on the comments above. Also make sure that the *--class* parameter points to the actual main class of the application.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. i am using --master spark://<complete-hostname-of-myspark-master>:7077 and it started working !!