# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure when integrating with MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, illegalstateexception

I am trying to integrate MongoDB with Apache Spark to process data. Here is my (dummy) code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;
import org.bson.BSONObject;
import org.bson.BasicBSONObject;
import java.util.Comparator;

import scala.Tuple2;

import com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoOutputFormat;
import com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat;
import com.mongodb.hadoop.BSONFileOutputFormat;

public final class JavaWordCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = args[0];
    String output = args[1];

        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext();

        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.set("mongo.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/" + input);
        config.set("mongo.job.input.format",                            "com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat");

//I have tryed with the same configuration for both too
    Configuration outputConfig = new Configuration();
    outputConfig.set("mongo.output.format",
                 "com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoOutputFormat");
    outputConfig.set("mongo.output.uri",
                 "mongodb://localhost:27017/"  + output);


        JavaPairRDD<Object, BSONObject> mongoRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(config, com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat.class, Object.class, BSONObject.class);

        // Input contains tuples of (ObjectId, BSONObject)
        JavaRDD<String> words = mongoRDD.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<Object, BSONObject>, String>() {
            @Override
            public Iterable<String> call(Tuple2<Object, BSONObject> arg) {
                Object o = arg._2.get("user");
                if (o instanceof String) {
                    String str = (String) o;
                    return Arrays.asList(str);
                } else {
                    return Collections.emptyList();
                }
            }
        });

        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> ones = words.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
            public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) {
                return new Tuple2<>(s, 1);
            }
        });

        // Output contains tuples of (null, BSONObject) - ObjectId will be generated by Mongo driver if null
        JavaPairRDD<Object, BSONObject> save = ones.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Object, BSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public Tuple2<Object, BSONObject> call(Tuple2<String, Integer> tuple) {
        BSONObject bson = new BasicBSONObject();
                bson.put("word", tuple._1);
                //bson.put("count", tuple._2);
                return new Tuple2<>(null, bson);
            }
        });

        // Only MongoOutputFormat and config are relevant

        save.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("file:///bogus", Object.class, BSONObject.class, MongoOutputFormat.class, outputConfig);

    }
}
```

It compiles perfectly with sbt and works as well using

```
../spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/spark-subt --master local --jars $(echo /home/luis/mongodb_old/mongo-spark/mongo-spark-master-3/lib/*.jar | tr ' ' ',') --class "JavaWordCount" target/scala-2.10/mongo-spark_2.10-1.0.jar mydb.testCollection mydb.output
```

But if I try

```
../spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/spark-subt --master spark://luis:7077 --jars $(echo /home/luis/mongodb_old/mongo-spark/mongo-spark-master-3/lib/*.jar | tr ' ' ',') --class "JavaWordCount" target/scala-2.10/mongo-spark_2.10-1.0.jar mydb.testCollection mydb.output
```

(that is, executing it in a standalone cluster instead of local) I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 6 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 6.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 23, ip184.com.uvigo.es): java.lang.IllegalStateException: open
    at org.bson.util.Assertions.isTrue(Assertions.java:36)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getPrimaryPort(DBTCPConnector.java:406)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:184)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:167)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:161)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:107)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:1049)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:1014)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.output.MongoRecordWriter.write(MongoRecordWriter.java:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:993)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:969)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1214)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1203)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1202)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1202)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1420)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor.aroundReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1375)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
15/03/02 13:31:26 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 8.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 22) on executor ip184.com.uvigo.es: java.lang.IllegalStateException (open) [duplicate 2]
```

I have tried solution posted in [Spark-Submit exception SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25722766/spark-submit-exception-sparkexception-job-aborted-due-to-stage-failure) but it didn't fix it. I have also read many other posts, but I cannot find the solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S.: I have tryed to follow all the rules before posting, but this is my first post in stackoverflow, so if I have made any error I apologize and promise not to do it any more.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I have upgraded to the newest version of Spark and MongoDB. I keep getting the same exception, but it seems to be captured internally, so the process doesn't stop. However, the data that caused the exception isn't processed, so I get different results after every execution. This is what I get now:

```
15/03/23 17:05:34 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 4, 10.0.2.15): java.lang.IllegalStateException: open
at org.bson.util.Assertions.isTrue(Assertions.java:36)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getPrimaryPort(DBTCPConnector.java:406)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:184)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:167)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:161)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:107)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:1049)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:1014)
at com.mongodb.hadoop.output.MongoRecordWriter.write(MongoRecordWriter.java:105)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1000)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:979)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

EDIT 2:
The MongoDB collection from which I tried to read had about 30,000 documents. I have just tried with one that just has 10,000 and it works like a charm, but it does not seem to be a very good solution. What can it be?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your output mongodb server seems to be configured to be :

```
"mongodb://localhost:27017/"
```

Are you sure ? Shouldn't it be a proper remote address that all your workers can reach ?

Regards,

Comment: @Oliver Giradot: I have tried "mongodb://my-ip:27017/" and comented up bind_ip = 127.0.0.1 in /etc/mongod.conf. I still get the same error. Thank you.